# Getting display:table-cell and position:absolute to play nicely

Tags: html, css

By default I have a `<ul>` that's hidden from view which becomes visible when hovering over the parent `<li>`. When it does come into view the parent `<li>` expands its width by 1px. For some reason this only happens when using display:table-cell on the list items, which I'd prefer to keep using given the ability to center vertically. But the 1px jump is unwanted.

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="downloads"><a>Downloads</a>
        <ul class="downloads-menu">
            <li>Download 1</li>
            <li>Download 2</li>
            <li>Download 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="about"><a>About</a></li>
    <li class="resources"><a>Resources</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>

ul.nav-menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

ul.nav-menu > li {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

li a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.nav-menu li.downloads:hover ul.downloads-menu {
    display: block;
}

ul.downloads-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

I've setup a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/azoc8c4m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.nav-menu > li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

li a {
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but with a bit of modifications I can make that work. Thanks.